# Unable to get refresh token in onedrive graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to the api doc we need to add a scope "offline_access" in user consent column as show in the screenshot attached, but when I click on grant consent it asks for the admin approval,

I have also looked the configurations form admin account but unable to provide the consent of offline access.

Please let me know which setting I am missing for granting the offline access scope to the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing the permissions from the **Enterprise Applications** blade. You need to first add the permission from the **App Registrations** blade, and then you can grant admin consent for it.

See [Configure required Azure AD Graph permissions for an app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-configure-permissions#option-1-use-the-azure-portal-to-find-the-apis-your-organization-uses)

Generally, the `offline_access` scope doesn't require admin consent, unless the  [User consent for applications setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal) has been disabled.